# how to get value of selected option using phpunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selection

I want to get the value of an option which is selected using PHPUnit code.
Do we have any function like the one below:

```
$this->byId('<selectname>')->selectValueBySelectedOption()
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just manually fetch the option using CSS:

```
var $value = $this->byCssSelector("select#selectId > option[selected]")->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: I got the error getAttribute is not existent or not supported yet. Do you know why? But when I tried, 
var $value = $this->byCssSelector("select#selectId > option[selected]")->value(); 
it worked.

Comment: The PHP version of Selenium is not as fleshed out as the java version. My guess is that it either hasn't been added, or it is named differently

Comment: You are right. My phpunit was at lower version. It worked after upgrading it to phpunit 4.0

Comment: @bestrahul21 great!  go ahead and accept the answer so this question can be closed

Comment: can you not just call getAttribute('value') on the select itself ?

Comment: @djfm do you mean by using JavaScript?

Comment: no I mean $this->byCssSelector("#selectId")->getAttribute('value'); I don't know the PHPUnit bindings but it seems to work with the facebook selenium php bindings

Comment: ah.. that most likely will work.  fetching either the select, or the option will work.  I just like specificity :)